# Still using WP Stats without Jetpack

Tags: statistics

The [WP Stats plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/stats/) has long been deprecated in favor of Jetpack.

Is there a way I can still use it on new WP installations?

I know it can be downloaded and installed but no longer be configured. Can the API key from one installation be extracted from its database and inserted into the database of another installation?

Comment: Why can't it be downloaded if you linked to repository with download available yourself?..

Comment: Uuhhmm, you got me, sorry.

Comment: Still have a question or that does it? :)